# Cordova build command windows 10 error

Tags: cordova, windows-10, cordova-cli

My project worked just fine until a week ago. Every time I try to build my project I get this error:

[screenshot windows build error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDdX8.png)

It is strange because it worked before without any problem...